# Keyboard input blocks in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-input

Since yesterday, I have a problem when  want to edit code in VSCode. Apparently, after changing focus within VSCode, say switching to the menu bar or a to different view and then coming back to the editor view, the cursor changed from the caret to a filled rectangle, and normal keyboard input is blocked. I need to do something like pressing the Escape key which on the first, second, or third try finally puts me into overwrite mode from which I have to switch to insert mode. This is a very annoying situation. Does anyone have a remedy for this?

Comment: Filled rectangle could mean you pressed the insert key

Comment: @Phiter: switching insert/replace mode only works after pressing escape key at least once; the problem also occurs after something like pressing ctl-s, so it's likely that the key-mapping scheme became disfunct somehow. The problem is that I don't want to create a new scheme from scratch (to much lookup necessary -tl;dr).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I happened somehow to switch to the vim schema. Once I became aware of this, I simply switched back to the VS schema which I'm used to, and everything works as desired.